# SharePoint Online - How to redirect a URL?

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, redirect

SharePoint Online- We recently migrated a site from an old location to a new location. Users have the link(URL) to our old site. How can i redirect the users to the new location(new URL) when the try to access the Old URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You "could" add a CEWP to the homepage to insert some javascript to redirect them automatically.

```
<script>
window.location.href = "https://sharepointtenant.sharepoint.com/";
</script>
```

Ideally, if you were coming from onprem, you could add this javascript to the 404 error page and turn off all the sites so that the 404 page will redirect them.